# \subsetneq in bold font

Tags: math-mode, symbols, bold

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\boldsymbol{\subsetneq}$

\end{document}
```

I got the symbol in roman only but I need in bold face, any suggestions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

works with package `bm`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm}
\begin{document}

    $\bm{\subsetneq}$ $\subsetneq$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using a proper mathfont also helps:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\begin{document}

    $\boldsymbol{\subsetneq}$ $\subsetneq$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Voss; Your second suggestion exactly suits for me...Thanks a lot...

Comment: It should be remarked, however, that the first alternative uses “poor man’s bold”.  With `\usepackage{kpfonts}`, the `\bm` command could also be used instead of `\boldsymbol`, producing “real” bold in the output, *provided* that the `bm` package is loded *after* `kpfonts`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `unicode-math`, there are three OpenType math fonts (as of 2019) that come in bold: Khaled Hosny’s free fonts XITS Math and Libertinus Math, and the commercial Minion Math.

The package will automatically load the bold weight as `version=bold`, but you can load any arbitrary OpenType or TrueType font with a command such as `\setmathfont[version=bold]{XITS Math Bold}`.

If you also load `amsmath`, `\boldsymbol{\subsetneq}` will still work.  The `unicode-math` package by itself still supports the legacy commands `{\boldmath ...}` and `{\mathversion{bold} ...}`.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative you could use or [`amsbsy`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsbsy) package putting the command `\pmb`.
See the image and MWE in attachment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsbsy}
\begin{document}
$\pmb{\subsetneq}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your suggestion works, but it seems to be overwriting of the same character...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Yes of course. Here can you see (for example) as works the command `\pmb` at this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/pmb.htm